# Custom wrapper for containers implementing __iter__ and __getitem__

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write a custom wrapper class for containers. To implement the iterator-prototocol I provide `__iter__` and `__next__` and to access individual items I provide `__getitem__`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals, with_statement
from future_builtins import *
import numpy as np

class MyContainer(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._position = 0
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.value[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if (self._position >= len(self.value)):
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self._position += 1
            return self.value[self._position - 1]
```

So far, everything works as expected, e. g. when trying things like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = MyContainer([1,2,3,4,5])
    print(a)
    iter(a) is iter(a)
    for i in a:
        print(i)
    print(a[2])
```

But I run into problems when trying to use `numpy.maximum`:

```
b= MyContainer([2,3,4,5,6])
np.maximum(a,b)
```

Raises "`ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with dimension 0`".

When commenting out the `__iter__` method, I get back a NumPy array with the correct results (while no longer conforming to the iterator protocol):

```
print(np.maximum(a,b)) # results in [2 3 4 5 6]
```

And when commenting out `__getitem__`, I get back an instance of `MyContainer`

```
print(np.maximum(a,b)) # results in [2 3 4 5 6]
```

But I lose the access to individual items.

Is there any way to achieve all three goals together (Iterator-Protocol, `__getitem__` and `numpy.maximum` working)? Is there anything I'm doing fundamentally wrong?

To note: The actual wrapper class has more functionality but this is the minimal example where I could reproduce the behaviour.

(Python 2.7.12, NumPy 1.11.1)

Comment: Why is your container its own (and only) iterator?

Comment: What does `np.array(MyContainer)` do?  np.mamimum works on arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj "print(np.array(MyContainer))" results in "<class '__main__.MyContainer'>", "print(np.array(MyContainer([1,2,3,4,5])))" results in the same ValueError as mentioned above.

Comment: Iterables should **not** return themselves as the *iterator*. Instead you could do `def __iter__(self): return (self[i] for i in range(len(self)))` which is basically the default iterator you get when you define `__getitem__` and `__len__`.

Comment: @Bakuriu You're saying that an object can be either an iterat**or** or an iter**able** but not both?

Comment: @grma0025 Yes. Doing so breaks iteration, as in your case: you end up with multiple references to the same iterator which if used concurrently result in strange effects.

Comment: @grma0025: An object should not be both an iterator and a *sequence*. Strictly speaking, all iterators are iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container is its own iterator, which limits it greatly. You can only iterate each container once, after that, it is considered "empty" as far as the iteration protocol goes.

Try this with your code to see:

```
c = MyContainer([1,2,3])
l1 = list(c) # the list constructor will call iter on its argument, then consume the iterator
l2 = list(c) # this one will be empty, since the container has no more items to iterate on
```

When you don't provide an `__iter__` method but do implement a `__len__` methond and a `__getitem__` method that accepts small integer indexes, Python will use `__getitem__` to iterate. Such iteration can be done multiple times, since the iterator objects that are created are all distinct from each other.

If you try the above code after taking the `__iter__` method out of your class, both lists will be `[1, 2, 3]`, as expected. You could also fix up your own `__iter__` method so that it returns independent iterators. For instance, you could return an iterator from your internal sequence:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.value)
```

Or, as suggested in a comment by [Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510937/bakuriu):

```
def __iter__(self):
    return (self[i] for i in range(len(self))
```

This latter version is essentially what Python will provide for you if you have a `__getitem__` method but no `__iter__` method.